# Как создать домен example.com в файле hosts на локальном сервере вместо localhost?

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, nginx, localhost

На Ubuntu 16.04 установил Nginx + php-fpm + MySql + phpmyadmin.
Подправил конфиги, закинул сайт. Все работает при открытии адреса в браузере `localhost`

Как сэмулировать локальный домен example.com, который бы открывался равнозначно localhost'у?

Гуглил про файл hosts, настроить не смог. Подскажите пример настройки

Comment: покажите свой вариант hosts, который не работает.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts